# wpf not refresh code if not focused

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, focus, backgroundworker

I have this situation: a class that contains a background worker that do some thing in a while cycle:

```
public class CControls
{
  public delegate void ControlChangedEventHandler();
  public event ControlChangedEventHandler ControlChangedEvent;

  private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;
  bool bClose = false;

  public CControls(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
  }

  void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    bClose = true;
  }

  public void enable(bool bEnable)
  {
    if (bEnable && !worker.IsBusy)
    {
      worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    else
    {
      bClose = true;
    }
  }

  void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    while (!bClose)
    {
      // my job
      // ..............................................
      //
      if (ControlChangedEvent != null)
      {
        ControlChangedEvent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have my form that create an instance of this class and set the listener of `ControlChangedEvent`:

```
CControls ct = new CControls();
ct.ControlChangedEvent += ct_ControlChangedEvent;
int changes = 0;

void ct_ControlChangedEvent()
{
  Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate
  {
    changes ++;
    infoLabel.Content = string.Format("changes: {0}", changes);
  });
}
```

but the infoLabel changes only if my program have the focus, otherwise is not fired...

any ideas?
thanks ;)

Comment: Could it be something to do with `DispatcherPriority.Background` ? Try `Normal`.

Comment: thanks @Sinatr, but just setting a breakpoint if is not focused is not fired, also outside the `Dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: Try to set breakpoint on `ControlChangedEvent();` row, maybe you have `continue` in your worker job cycle (which occurs if window is not focused) ;)

Comment: in the worker job cycle the breakpoint is hit also if is not focused, but in the usercontrol `ct_ControlChangedEvent` doesn't arrive

Comment: Check subscribers when breakpoint is hit. Maybe you are using dynamic event subscription (not really clear from example) or dynamic control creating. I know in `winforms` you have to check for `IsHandleCreated`, maybe something similar is here; what is *focus*? You still have window opened and visible, etc? Simply switch to another window (Alt-Tab) while leaving `infoLabel` visible on screen and its not updated anymore? Can you prepare a small project to reproduce a problem?